# Trying to add my strings to my aplication using an include statement

Tags: php, include

I am busy creating my first PHP site after deciding to move out of wordpress and gain full control over what I wanted to do (to be honest I found creating types a nightmare)
I am now trying to list all of my error strings important statements as variables in a php file, which I then include, with the language in the name, like strings_en.php, so it can create the name of the php file from the language being used by the user. I am having trouble displaying the values of variables from the included file. Will this work? Or is the trade off of loading that many string into memory too much?

Comment: This will likely get closed for being opinion based. Yes it will probably work. Unless you have hundreds of thousands of very long strings having it loaded probably won't be a problem. But I can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do

```
<?php
   $lang = "en";
   require_once "strings_$lang";

   echo $error_login;
```

and `strings_en.php` contains

```
<?php
   $error_login = "You are not connected";
```

In the headers of the files that require the global variables.

It's very unlikely you will run out of memory. For your information, a standard vanilla WordPress page goes through 443 files and 180,000 lines of code in 4 seconds in less than 128Mb.
WordPress is good for editing though. Without the CMS, you would either need to code things by hand, create your own CMS or use a graphical word processor for websites.